# Biber/BibLaTex: How to change "n.d."-letters into custom-letters in case of missing date of literature-entry?

Tags: biblatex, biber

How can I change the "n.d."-letters generated in case of a missing date into custom letters (e.g. "o. J.")?

---

**Working minimum-example:**

```
% ==== PREAMBEL =============================================================

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[
                citestyle=numeric,
                style=authoryear,
                natbib=true,
                backend=biber
            ]{biblatex}            % Use Biber and BibLaTex instead of BibTex

\usepackage{filecontents}

% ==== BIBLIOGRAPHY ========================================================

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 

@book{Doe,
    author = {Doe, Jon},
    title = {How to cite a literature-entry containing date},
    date = {2015},

}

@book{Dae,
    author = {Dae, Liz},
    title = {How to cite a literature-entry with missing date},
    date = {date},
}

\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname} 

% ==== DOCUMENT ============================================================

\begin{document}

\chapter{Experimental chapter}

    This is a text for testing how to cite a literature-entry containing date \parencite[look at][]{Doe}.

    This is a text for testing how to cite a literature-entry with missing date \parencite[look at][]{Dae}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of citation inside the text:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot of bibliography:**

[image]

---

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

```
% ==== PREAMBEL =============================================================

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[
    citestyle=numeric,
    style=authoryear,
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex} % Use Biber and BibLaTex instead of BibTex

\usepackage{filecontents}

% ==== BIBLIOGRAPHY ========================================================

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Doe,
author = {Doe, Jon},
title = {How to cite a literature-entry containing date},
date = {2015},

}

@book{Dae,
author = {Dae, Liz},
title = {How to cite a literature-entry with missing date},
```

% date = {nodate},
    }

```
@online{Lear,
title ={Edward Lear Home Page},
url = {http://www.nonsenselit.org/Lear/pstories/cm/cm.html},
urldate = {2015-07-16},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
nodate = {{}o\adddot\addnbthinspace J\adddot}
    }%
\DeclareLabeldate{%
\field{date}
\field{eventdate}
\field{origdate}
\literal{nodate}
}

%
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
{\printtext[parens]{\printfield{labelyear}}}
{\printtext[parens]{%
\printfield{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}%
\printfield{extrayear}}}}% ==== DOCUMENT ============================================================

\begin{document}

\chapter{Experimental chapter}

This is a text for testing how to cite a literature-entry containing date \parencite[look at][]{Doe}.

This is a text for testing how to cite a literature-entry with missing date \parencite[look at][]{Dae}.

Edward Lear revisited Roman history \parencite[look at]{Lear}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you also want to make sure there is a thin space between "o." and "J.". You could go with `{o\addd\addnbthinspace J.\adddot}` then. The default in `german.lbx` (`{}o\adddot D\adddot}`) which you may or may not have based your answer on looks somewhat weird to me.

Comment: @moewe: I did base my answer on german.lbx, and noticed the lack of thin space. I looked at a few sites such as (www.abkuerzungen.de) and didn't see any thin space (as for the French `n.d.`). Now I know seeing a thin unbreakable space on the Web must be a rather rare event… Do you really thonk I should add one?

Comment: As far as I know, the space should be there; I could not find a rule in my Duden, but all two-word abbreviations with dots also there feature a space. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abk%C3%BCrzung#Abk.C3.BCrzungen_mit_Punkt.2C_aber_ohne_Leerzeichen) also claims that the form without a space is deprecated and only allowed in some special cases. And for what it's worth, I think it looks appalling without any white space. (As for the internet sites you frequented: I think there are more concerned with the meaning of the abbreviations and not the typographically correct presentation.)

Comment: If you like I will investigate this a bit further, but later.

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you very much for your help, it work's perfectly! At moewe: Thank you, too! I also only know the type of writing with (!) the thin space between the o. and J., so I'm going to use your adaption.

Comment: @Moewe: Thank you, I'd be delighted. I hardly have some notions of German.

Comment: @Bernard: Excuse me, unfortunately there is one more question: If I use an online-source (type: @online) without a date, Biber falsely sets the date of URL-access automatically as the date of creation as well... How can I put the "o. J." as the date of creation in this case, too? The date of URL-access should be shown in the bibliography nevertheless, of course... :-)

Comment: @Dave: It's solved, see my updated answer. There remains a small problem though: I don't understand why `@online` citations look different from the other two.

Comment: OK, I did some more research and my Duden tells me that a non-breaking space is used in abbreviations (see *Festabstände* in the section *Textverarbeitung und E-Mails*, p. 108 in my 24th edition from 2006). This advice seems to be [DIN 5008 conform](http://www.din-5008-richtlinien.de/abkuerzungen.php). It also notes that these spaces are often thinner than a standard white space. So I would definitely opt for a thin space here.

Comment: Thanks. I'lll do it at once. So this is definitely different from French.

Comment: Rummaging round on the internet reveals that some people don't like to use any space because the lonely letters look to far apart (they should probably use thin spaces). Apparently, there are even school textbooks around that don't use spaces. The consensus seems to be that while the version without a space is quite widespread (especially on the internet), the version with a space is considered to be the "correct" one (the version one would use when writing an important document, for example).

Comment: I find it quite interesting that French would drop the space here, when it is so liberal with spaces before colons and questions marks and such ...

Comment: Just one more: http://www.abkuerzungen.de/ uses ["i.Allg." in its lookup table](http://www.abkuerzungen.de/result.php?searchterm=i.+Allg%2C) without a space, but then does have a space when the abbreviation is used in its [miscellaneous section](http://www.abkuerzungen.de/thisandthat.php?language=de&style=standard). So you can't even trust websites dedicated to abbreviations to settle for one way of writing them.

Comment: One (hopefully really) last thing: The `@online` citation probably just looks different because it does not have an author and the title is then used to identify it instead ("o. N. o. J." as in *no name, no date* would just look odd).

Comment: Not so liberal. What makes it complex, is that strictly speaking, it can be a thin space or a medium space, and I confess that if I hac=ve to do it by hand, I always have to check. For acronyms, it's also complex: there's no space, but we use small caps if  the acronym has to be spelled (i. e. if it can't be read as a word), otherwise textcase ($\textsc{Sncf}$ vs Maif).

Comment: ... Sorry, it's me again: I would use `\addnbthinspace`, i.e. a thin space that cannot be broken instead of a breakable thins pace as in your current answer.

Comment: I thought \addthinspace was unbeakable, just like   `\,`…